# Facebook session data not recovering

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm on Unity 5.1.1, Facebook 7.0.2 beta and testing on Android 5.1 and iOS 8.4 devices.

I'm doing `FB.Init();` with `"status = true"` to recover the session and "autologin". But my problem is that it doesn't work. When I call `Init` in `onInitComplete` callback `FB.IsLoggedIn` returns always `false`.

I have tried in my project and in a blank project with the example scene. In the example scene I click on `FB.Init`, `FB.Login`, I log in then I close the app and open again and I have to login again.

Is it a bug?

Comment: sounds like a legit bug. I recommend filing a bug report on developers.facebook.com/bugs. To speed up the fixing, please include a minimal sample test project (like the blank project you're mentioning). Bonus points if you use the InteractiveConsole scene included in the SDK to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issue. It is a bug on Facebook's part. The result of the Init call doesn't seem to include any information about the player at all. In fact, it includes different type of useless data depending on the current platform.

Facebook has acknowledged the bug and they said it's fixed in the next build which hasn't been released yet. You can see the bug and that acknowledgment here.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1459551294340956/?search_id